# Probability, Poisson Process, My solution is correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Jobs are submitted for a computer according to a Poisson process with a rate λ
(jobs / hour).
Determine the probability of at least two jobs are submitted within the 'a' first few minutes.

I tried simplify things with numbers:

Example:

```
λ

6 jobs --- 60 minutes
x jobs --- 5 minutes
x = 0.5 jobs/5 minutes
```

"at least two jobs are submitted" = `P(X>=2) = 1 - P(X<2) = 1 - P(X<=1)`

```
λ jobs -- 60 minutes
x jobs -- 'a' minutes

(λ*a)/60 jobs/'a' minutes.

P(X<=1)......= e^(-λ) [(λ^0)/0! + (λ^1)/1!]
.............= e^(-λ) ( 1 + λ )
.............= e^[-(λ*a)/60] * [1 + (λ*a)/60] 

1 - P(X<=1) = 1 - {e^[-(λ*a)/60] * [1 + (λ*a)/60]}
```

This solution is consistent?

What do you think?

Comment: It is correct. The number of jobs rate per $a$ minutes has Poisson distribution with mean $a \lambda/60$. Call this $\mu$. Then the probability of $2$ or more jobs in $a$ minutes is $1-e^{-mu} -e^{-\mu}\mu$. Your solution was very detailed. It may be a good idea to get accustomed to defining your random variables, in this case $X$, explicitly. Here it is clear to you and the reader what you mean by $X$. But in other cases one can lose track.

Comment: But it is not a Poisson distribuition. It is a Poisson process.

Comment: The solution in the language of processes is the same.